# Calculating and plotting a 20 year Climatology

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, python-xarray

I am working on plotting a 20 year climatology and have had issues with averaging.
My data is hourly data since December 1999 in CSV format. I used an API to get the data and currently have it in a pandas data frame. I was able to split up hours, days, etc like this:

```
dfROVC1['Month'] = dfROVC1['time'].apply(lambda cell: int(cell[5:7]))
dfROVC1['Day'] = dfROVC1['time'].apply(lambda cell: int(cell[8:9]))
dfROVC1['Year'] = dfROVC1['time'].apply(lambda cell: int(cell[0:4]))
dfROVC1['Hour'] = dfROVC1['time'].apply(lambda cell: int(cell[11:13]))
```

So I averaged all the days using:

```
z=dfROVC1.groupby([dfROVC1.index.day,dfROVC1.index.month]).mean()
```

That worked, but I realized I should take the average of the mins and average of the maxes of all my data. I have been having a hard time figuring all of this out.
I want my plot to look like this:
[Monthly Average Section](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html#monthly-averaging)
but I can't figure out how to make it work.
I am currently using Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you didn't just use datetime to convert your time column?

The minimums by month would be:

```
z=dfROVC1.groupby(['Year','Month']).min()
```

Comment: There was no reason as to why I did it that way. I just found that it applied, but Datetime would probably be easier for me to do. Thank you for that.

Comment: Also, I see that this line works better when written this way, but how would I be able to plot it? I've been having issues with plotting using this groupby function as well. I'm not sure if you have better documentation or explanations than what I have found

Comment: You can't plot groupby objects - presumably you're talking about  plotting the result, which has dimensions along the lines of (lat, lon, year, month)? This would then be a question of how to plot four-dimensional data. You could average across years and plot each month in a different subplot (see xarray docs on [faceting](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html#faceting)), or a ton of other options.